# How to filter file types (extensions) while using the chrome media galleries api

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

First post here.

I fall squarely into the category of "severely new". So, if you are kind enough to respond to this question, please assume the following:

- If it's a code other than an if else statement, I probably need detailed instructions about how that code works and where it goes.

So, in other words, while I appreciate your help in advance, please don't say "Oh, no problem, just wrhimuss the frammus with a 4:3 array".

OK, caveat over, here's my deal:

I've been working (playing) around with the [chrome media gallery sample app](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/media-gallery) in an attempt to create a small gallery/player for webm video files, and after a week or so of work it's coming together quite nicely if you ignore the terribly organized code and css problems but somehow I made it work (mostly because most of the work was already done).

The chrome media gallery sample app adds to the gallery list every media file (music, pictures, video) it can find and that's the issue I'm trying to address here. I tried deleting every reference to pictures, music and others from the js code but the files still appear on the list only now they can't be "played". I want to make the gallery webm only, maybe mp4 or even every video type but that's it, no pictures and no audio.

So, any suggestions as to how I can fix this issue?

Thanks very much in advance!

**EDIT:**
This is the code I'm using: [JS](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8157384) (not very different, is it?). I believe the solution is in lines 121 or 152 but I'm too much of a novice to know what to do.

**EDIT2:**
Yeah, I was right after all. Finally managed to make it work the way I wanted, can't believe it was that simple. Thanks for all your help, you can consider this question solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I just replaced line [152](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8157384#file-gistfile1-js-L152) with this:

```
var path = entries[i].name;
var type = getFileType(path);
if (entries[i].isFile && type == "video") {
```

It sends the entries' names to the [getFileType](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8157384#file-gistfile1-js-L52) function and returns if the entry is a video.

Answer (score 1):

At https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/media-gallery/media-gallery.js#L113 the sample checks what type of media each file is, and does something different for images, audio, and video. If you only care about video, you can just grab the video ones and do whatever you want, ignoring the others.

Comment: Yes thank you. That's what I tried but the music and pictures still make it to the gallery list in the app. They can't be opened though since no image/audio element is created. I just want them out of that list. Any suggestions?

Comment: Would probably help if you can post your code on github or something. Maybe just as a "gist" if you don't want to make an official repo and such.

Comment: Here it is: [jsCode](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8106713)  I think I just deleted lines 7, 8, 48 to 61, 73 to 76 and 114 to 117 from the original and added a cluster of code of my own at the end.